# Deactivate plugin on specific page

Tags: wordpress

How I deactivate "WooCommerce Product Sort and Display LITE" plugin on search results page.Because it conflicts with search results.Can you please help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript');
  function my_deregister_javascript() {
    if ( !is_page('Contact') ) {//pagename
       wp_deregister_script( 'WooCommerce ' );//pluginname
    }
 }
```

it detect wooommerce script except contact page.